# How to enable FF_GITLAB_REGISTRY_HELPER_IMAGE or alternative with Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We are using Gitlab CI/CD for our build process. Recently, we started bumping up against the error message:

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: image pull failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

[Gitlab recommends](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#migrating-helper-image-to-registrygitlabcom) adding `FF_GITLAB_REGISTRY_HELPER_IMAGE` it seems to the config.toml for runners.
I use Gitlab's CI/CD to autodeploy on EKS through AWS. Consequently, I don't have access to a set configurable runner.
I tried adding:

```
FEATURE_FLAG_NAME: 1
FF_GITLAB_REGISTRY_HELPER_IMAGE: 1
```

to gitlab-ci.yml to no effect.

I am looking at the using the dependency proxy discussed [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/dependency_proxy/index.html#use-the-dependency-proxy-for-docker-images) but it doesn't seem to have much of an effect.

Question:
How can I have Gitlab's autodeploy use the gitlab runner helper images with an EKS deployment?

How can the gitlab-ci.yml be configured to use a docker token to pull images?

Comment: Did you solve this by any chance?

Comment: Yes, a combination of things. My apologies - I thought I had documented it. 
I believe it was a few things - I was going to mention using kubectl to set the booleans mentioned above and below. 
However, I believe what fixed it was pushing copies of all the images to the gitlab image repository and making sure that was what was configured to pull the images.

Comment: So basically all the images are now prefaced with: `image: registry.gitlab.com/ourproject/`

Answer (score 1):

in your .gitlab-ci.yml file set as a global variable like below.

```
variables:
  FF_GITLAB_REGISTRY_HELPER_IMAGE: "true"
```

that should work.

You can check https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#custom-cicd-variables for gitlab-ci variables.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Any other way to resolve this?